# Blackberry JDE or Eclipse Plugin for developing Blackberry applications

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I use for now the Blackberry JDE for developing blackberry applications. And I am so familiar with it. I spent six months developing on this software.

I installed Blackberry plugin for ecplise last week to try it and see if it is better. Well Eclipse helps you more in writing the code, much easier. But some difference exist espacially in locating the images.

I am afraid that when starting projects on eclipse, I wouldn't be able to move them to JDE.

So what are your recommendations? Which is best to use? Blackberry plugin for eclipse or JDE? If you recommend me moving to eclipse than why? Is there some benefits that are worth this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding in JDE is a nightmare. Six months!.. :)

I still use Eclipse just for coding + JDE just for building/debugging. This tandem works just nice for me. Approximately a year ago I gave a try to BB plugin for Eclipse, however there was some issue with the plugin (unfortunatelly now I don't remember what exactly) so I dropped the idea of using BB plugin. Probably by now the plugin became better, however I don't know any substantial reason of why I should give it a try again.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is standard for developers, at least for Java, including app engine and Android. You can do all your projects from it, with helpful plugins and regular updates for the BB plugin from RIM and Eclipse itself is also regularly updated. The JDE is a monster from the past with an at least 10-year-old UI that is still dragging along; only time I used it was for an alpha release of BlackBerry 7 (that was called 6.1 at the time).